# Simple SQL Count to LINQ?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I've spent the last two hours or so researching this.  Is new to LINQ btw.
How do I get an SQL like this to a LINQ query?

```
SELECT      r.id, name, designation, COUNT(a.id)
FROM        region r
LEFT JOIN   area a on a.region_id = r.id
GROUP BY    r.id, name, designation
```

My alternative of course is to place this in a `View` (which I can figure out) but I'd like this to be added to my knowledge.  Thanks!

P.S. Either VB or C# will do but I'd prefer the former.

Comment: Do you have a group clause in your SQL? Otherwise your COUNT doesn not make sense.

Comment: The SQL is incorrect since you need to group by `r.id`, `name` and `designation`

Comment: Oh sheesh, my bad. Fixed, and thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be like this:

```
var result =
            from r in regions
            join a in areas on r.id equals a.region_id into subvalues
            select new { id = r.id, name = r.name, designation = r.designation, count = subvalues.Count() };
```

Comment: Is this Inner Join or Left Join ?

Comment: This is left join.

Comment: Then how is inner join done in the same sql format query ?

Comment: Can you explain the second `From`? Because I was able to do it without that line. Thanks

Comment: @AwonDanag Edited it. I had a bad habit. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group the data, try a query that looks something like this:

```
var countQry =
    from region in Regions
    let areas =
        from area in Areas
        where area.RegionId == region.Id
        select area
    select new {
        region.Id,
        region.Name,
        region.Designation,
        AreaCount = areas.Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this also could work right..

```
int count = 0;

(from r in region
join a in area on r.<join_val> equals a.<join_val> into leftJ
from lj in leftJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
select lj
).GroupBy( r => r.id).All(item => 
{ 
count += item.Count();
return true;
});
```

count should have the value u are looking for,